# Tshark can not be initiated under WSL (Windows Subsystem Linux) ((socket: Adress Family not supported by protocoll))

Tags: debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wireshark, tshark

I'm visiting a computer network course.
For learning purposes I'd like to run tshark in my WSL-Debian under Windows.

I succesfully installed it using: `sudo apt-get install tshark`

My Version using `tshark -v` --> `TShark (Wireshark) 3.4.10 (Git v3.4.10 packaged as 3.4.10-0+deb11u1)`

`sudo tshark -D` Outputs several "ports" (?)

but when i use the simple command `tshark`
It says: "Capturing on 'eth0'
tshark: The capture session could not be initiated on interface 'eth0' (socket: Address family not supported by protocol)....."

Is it an illusion to run tshark on WSL? I've read somewhere that it should be possible

-edit:
Working on WSL1

Comment: Are you on WSL1 or WSL2 and which version?

Comment: Currently im on WSL1 (I've read, while searching for the solution, that WSL2 has/had some network-issues. So I stayed on WSL1)

Comment: Some sources say that WSL2 is better for that, which is why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love WSL, but it probably isn't the right tool for you in this case.  Neither WSL1 nor WSL2 is "great" for running any packet capturing, for differing reasons:

- WSL1, in my experience, isn't going to work at all.  Network interfaces in WSL1 are not "real" Linux network interfaces.  All Linux syscalls in WSL1 go through a "translation layer" where they are matched to Windows APIs.  There are advantages and disadvantages to this.  While, you really *can* see the Windows network interfaces with Linux commands (e.g. `ip addr`), these are *Windows* network interfaces, not Linux.

  As such, there's only "so much" that has been translated.  And dang, IMHO, WSL1 does an amazing job of running so much with those limitations, but promiscuous network captures are not one of the things that are translated.
- WSL2, on the other hand, is a *real* Linux kernel running in a *virtualized* environment.  `tshark` will run and capture packets originating from and destined to the virtual network, but it won't see (for example) traffic between your phone and your Windows host on the WiFi network.  WSL2 has no concept of that WiFi network, since it's NAT'd behind the virtual Hyper-V switch.

Regardless, at the least you should switch to WSL2 for this.

However, I would recommend that the better option for your course would be running several virtual machines with something like VirtualBox (or even Hyper-V if you have Windows Pro or Education).  This will give you complete control over the virtual network; WSL just won't give that to you.

Comment: Hi @NotTheDr01ds, thank you very much for your explanations! I suspected already something similar like your explanation with WSL1. 

I have already an installed VirtualBox and will probably follow your recomendation.
And I will switch also to WSL2! Thanks again for your help! WSL does a very good job indeed, i thought it would be very convenient. :-D